# Get view's frame in UIView that is not superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I would think this is a simple question, but I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

I have a view that is a subview of my uiviewcontroller. Within that view, I have another view. To clarify, this is the architecture:

```
>UIViewController.view
--->Subview A
------->Subview B
```

I want to get the frame of `subview b` within `uiviewcontroller.view`.

Is this possible? `subviewB.frame` gives me the frame of the view within `Subview A`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `UIView convertRect:toView:` method:

```
CGRect frameRelativeToViewControllerView = [subviewB convertRect:subviewB.bounds toView:viewController.view];
```